# Giving the state instance to another class

Tags: flutter, dart

Before, I gave the `state` instance to another class like this
It worked.

```
class QBox{
  _KeyPageState parent; // declare variable

  QBox(p){
         parent = p; //get state in constructor
  }
}

class _KeyPageState extends State<KeyPage> {
   void initState(){
     super.initState();
     qBox = new QBox(this); //gave state here.
   }
}
```

However after updating flutter this error happens.

`Error: Field 'parent' should be initialized because its type '_KeyPageState' doesn't allow null.`

How can I avoid this error??

Comment: late _KeyPageState parent; see if this works.

Comment: `late` key also works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an initialization list, instead of assigning `parent` in the body of the constructor:

```
QBox(_KeyPageState p): parent = p;
```

More info here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Also though, this is an anti-pattern – Having the child and parent reference each other can cause memory leaks, among other issues. If you need to pass some info from the child to the parent, usually the best way is to use callbacks

Comment: I see giving parent reference is not good anti-pattern. Thank you